# Searching through tables (String name) with for loop (in Lua)

Tags: for-loop, lua, tree, lua-table

I got following problem (in Lua):

I have 20 tables named tree01, tree02 , ... , tree20.
Now I want to search the content of these tables but I can't find a solution how to refer to a tree with for.

```
for i=tree01,tree20 do
 --blablabla
```

Obviously I can't count it this way. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tree[1]`, ..., `tree[20]` are global variables then you can do this:

```
for i=1,20 do
  local t=_G[string.format("tree%02d",i)]
  -- blablabla
end
```

But it'd be much better if you had one table containing 20 tables: `tree[1]`, ..., `tree[20]`.

Comment: Thanks i tried using a table containing 20 tables as well and worked perfectly! Thanks :)